# How to get around waiting for function that has to be executed on another thread in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, c, multithreading

I have a function that has to be called on the main thread, however I'm operating on a different thread than the main thread. I'm working with **C** style functions in Objective-C, so **unfortunately I can't rely on a completion handler.**

This function is used by a lower level C library to retrieve data from my higher level implementation of the library. That being the case, I can't modify the signature of the function. The function must return an int and take no parameters, which means I'm unable to pass a completion handler to it. However, the code that I need to retrieve the data for the library must be executed on the main thread.

Currently, I'm using the following code to work around this issue:

```
int check_need_transition() {

    // Create the return value variable
    __block int bool_val = -1;

    // Execute the code that needs to be run on
    // on the main thread.
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        bool_val = compareStates() ? 0 : 1; 
    });

    // Wait for the main thread execution to complete
    while (bool_val == -1)
        sleep (0.1);

    // Return the value
    return bool_val;
}
```

I recognize that this is no the best way to do this, as it leaves a lot of potential to bugs like infinite looping etc. So, what is the best way to go about doing this properly?

Comment: You realize that you're using a block in the call to `dispatch_async()`, right? If you can use it there, why can't you use one for a completion handler? Anyway, much better than a loop around `sleep()` (which, as you note, has many problems) would be to use a proper thread synchronization mechanism, such as a semaphore. GCD provides those.

Comment: Sidenote: names starting with underscore at file-scope are reserved for the implementation. (Names starting with two underscores are reserved for all scopes).

Comment: @KenThomases I suppose I should clarify. This function is used by a lower level C library to retrieve data from my higher level implementation of the library. That being the case, I can't modify the signature of the function. The function must return an int and take no parameters, which means I'm unable to pass a completion handler to it. However, the code that I need to retrieve the data for the library must be executed on the main thread.

Comment: Still not clear what you are trying, but it looks like an XY problem. A low-level library depending on a high-level library sounds quite fishy.

Comment: @Olaf The low level library requires a configuration to be passed to it. Within this configuration is a function pointer that the library uses to retrieve specific information about the higher level environment. It needs the function to be of a specific signature in order to call it when necessary. I wouldn't say the low level library is depending on the high level implementation, it's only relying on it to provide information about the high level environment in order to decide how to perform specific tasks. In this case the information can only be retrieved on the main thread.

Comment: @NathanFiscaletti: That supports the suspection of a bad architecture -> XY problem, indeed.

Comment: _"bad architecture"_ Sounds like just another datasource relationship to me, no different than a table view.

Comment: @NathanFiscaletti, you can put whatever code you want in the same block as your call to `compareStates()`. Such code can, for example, use GCD to dispatch a completion handler to a background thread. Or, if `check_need_transition()` really, really needs to be synchronous, it can signal a semaphore.

Comment: @JoshCaswell: Circular dependencies with a low-level lib depending on a high-level lib are just bad architecture. Nothing against a common library, though. That could be plain C, instantly eliminating all issues.